# Two sessions and two different lifetime in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, session

If change Laravel lifetime sessions in `.env` file it works for all sessions. How can I determine the lifetimes of every session separately?

Comment: config/session.php defines session primarily to env. In env you can define just anything

Comment: I did not understand what you meant, unfortunately. can you explain more ?

Comment: I mean, in all cases I know, Laravel gets its values from config files. So the config/session.php should be the source of truth. However, session.php can get its values from environmental variables.
I was not able to figure out how to do what you asked, but very curious. Please post an answer if you found it.